# In loop to display fields from EF table, I want to convert boolean to empty space if False

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, format

these 2 lines are booleans in the database, checkboxes on the add record page.
But when I display rows entered, I want to have empty space where value is False (checkbox was not checked, field in table saves False).

```
    <td align="center">@m.IsTOTPresent</td>
    <td align="center">@m.IsEColi</td>
```

I'm thinking there is an if conditional that would change how it looks on the webpage based on the boolean result of true or false. In my case, nothing displayed would be optimum for false, and a red "true" with a grey background would be optimum for a true result. In a perfect world, that is.

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking for.  Do you want a tri-state checkbox with values true, false, and null/not-set?  Your db field would have to allow null, and when the data is bound to the view you would need to handle null as a special case of false.

Comment: No. all that is done. data gets entered correctily. When displaying the data, I would like to conditionally format it. "false" returns nothing (null, empty space, nada, niet, blank). "true" returns simply itself or if possible something a little more attention getting (red, gray background).
In VBA it would be:
IIf([IsTOTPresent]=false,""",[IsTOTPresent])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish what you're asking for.  Here are a couple...

---

### 1. Mostly razor

CSS:

```
.myTrue {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
};

.myFalse {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
};
```

Markup/Razor:

```
<td align='center' class='@(m.IsTOTPresent ? "myTrue" : "myFalse")'>@(m.IsTOTPresent ? "true" : "")</td>
<td align='center' class='@(m.IsEColi? "myTrue" : "myFalse")'>@(m.IsEColi? "true" : "")</td>
```

---

### 2. Mostly js

Markup/Razor:

```
<td align='center' data-boolean-value="@m.IsTOTPresent"></td>
<td align='center' data-boolean-value="@m.IsEColi"></td>
```

js:

```
(function() {
     document.querySelectorAll('[data-boolean-value]').forEach(
         function (obj, idx, arr) {
             if (typeof obj.dataset.booleanValue !== 'undefined') {
                 if(obj.dataset.booleanValue) {
                     obj.innerHTML = "true";
                     obj.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                     obj.style.color = "white";
                 } else {
                     obj.innerHTML = "";
                     obj.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                     obj.style.color = "black";
                 }
             }
         });
})();
```

Comment: I used this answer but had to modify slightly. Notice your align='center' for the <td> also included the boolean style switch. Used a span class to just affect the value not the whole <td> 
                <td align='center'><span class='@(m.IsTOTPresent ? "myTrue" : "myFalse")'>@(m.IsTOTPresent ? "POSITIVE" : "")</span></td>
                <td align='center'><span class='@(m.IsEColi ? "myTrue" : "myFalse")'>@(m.IsEColi ? "POSITIVE" : "")</span></td>

Comment: @JustJohn sorry, hadn't seen the `align` attribute used in a while.  I'm used to seeing 'center' as a css class now, so I accidentally added the new class to the align attribute's value.  I have corrected the answer.  Use of a span is a good idea though, and closer to what I would do myself, I just didn't want to add to your markup any more than necessary.